# jsoup to get the data in a unorderedlist

Tags: java, jsoup

I am using JSOUP to extract the data.
I have a html file:

```
=
<ul>
<li>
<i>
<a class="Class1" title="title1" href=""www.title1.com">title1</a>
</i>
(one)
</li>
<li>
<i>
<a title=title2" href="www.title2.com">title2</a>
</i>
(two)
</li>
<li>
<i>
<a title="title3" href=""www.title2.com">title3</a>
</i>
(three)
</li>
</ul>
```

How to use JSOUP to print title1,title2 and title3,
2) How to print the hrefs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty easy:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element link = doc.select("a").first();
String title1 = link.attr("title");

//etc.
```

Have you looked [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html)?

Also make sure the HTML is [well formed](http://www.cogsci.ed.ac.uk/~richard/xml-check.html). e.g. matching quotes

The HTML output above is not well formed, for instance:

```
<a class="Class1" title="title1" href=""www.title1.com">title1</a>
                                       ^ extra quote

<a title=title2" href="www.title2.com">title2</a>
         ^ missing quote
```

JSoup **requires** valid HTML.

Comment: I tried that and it is not working...yes I saw that link I was able to do some of the operations using JSON. This is the isue I am seeing for unordered list

Comment: JSoup can easily skip over lists. Also remove the extra quote from the hrefs - otherwise you will get nothing returned.

Comment: I did not get what you said.sorry..can you be more detail. I am not getting anything returned. the snip I gave is from a page I want to extract data and I have no control on that page

Comment: This really did not work as The website I am trying to extract is not as per HTML syntex. Thanks Reimeus. I will post a different message for the correct syntex