# JSOUP to get a un ordered list

Tags: java, jsoup

I am re posting this message.
I am trying to extract a unordered list. In the previous question I have the fomrat incorrect.
This website from where I am trying to extract the data is formatted correctly.

```
<ul>
<li>
<i>
<a class="mw-redirect" title="title1" href="yahoo.com">used to be a best email</a>
</i>
(1999)
</li>
<li>
<i>
<a title="title2" href="google.com">Best search enginee We Will Go</a>
</i>
(1999)
</li>
<li>
<i>
<a title="title3" href="apple.com">Best Phone</a>
</i>
(1990)
</li>
</ul>
```

I want to print:

title1

google.com

yahoo.com

=
used to be a best email
Best search email will go
Bestphone

similarly all Hrefs.

I did see the JSOUP documentation.

Related Question:
[jsoup to get the data in a unorderedlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015299/jsoup-to-get-the-data-in-a-unorderedlist)
but that is having format issues.

I tried as suggested but it is not working

I tried:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();             
Element link = doc.select("a").last();
String title1 = link.attr("title");
```

Issue is this is a big page with some information. in that there are many unordered lists..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe my answer would be more accurate if you would format and specify your requirements better, is this what you were looking for ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String html = "<ul><li><i><a class=\"mw-redirect\" title=\"title1\" href=\"yahoo.com\">used to be a best email</a></i>(1999)</li><li><i><a title=\"title2\" href=\"google.com\">Best search enginee We Will Go</a></i>(1999)</li><li><i><a title=\"title3\" href=\"apple.com\">Best Phone</a></i>(1990)</li></ul>";

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

        Elements links = doc.select("ul li i a");

        for (Element element : links) {
            System.out.format("%s %s %s\n", element.attr("title"), element.attr("href"), element.text());
        }
    }
```

If not add a sample output section in your question.

**Update :**

How it works. The `ul li i a` is a css selector. Which would mean take every `a` element that is located inside `i` that is wrapped in `li` tags which is wrapped in `ul` tags. (Horrible explanation)

You would get the same result from `doc.select("a")` as well. But being specific is better since you're parsing this data from some website because links can be in different places with different id/class or whatever and you are looking for these specific ones.

Yes if the selected elemets do have title, hyperlink and text value it will output that data.

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for. Can you please explain me how the JSOUP work sin this case? we gave "ul li i a" so it will grep all the ones with tag ul (or) li (or) i (or) a and when ever we give element.attr("title"), element.attr("href"), element.text() it will take from that greped list if these elements are valid and print? plese let me know

Comment: There I've updated the answer, if you like it please consider accepting it.